# console.logの履歴にアクセスしたいのですがどうすればよいでしょうか？

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-devtools

chromeのconsole上において(iframeで読み込まれ勝手に)consoleに出力されたものを
文字列として変数に入れてhtmlに出力したいのですが
どのような方法がありますでしょうか？

よろしくお願いいたします。

Comment: 念のため確認です: 対応するドキュメント (iframeがあるドキュメント) 内に結果を出力したい、ということで合っていますか?

Answer (score 2):

ライブラリを使わない方法(のヒント)を提示しておきます。

## オリジンが同じ場合

iframe の DOM ノードには `contentWindow` というオブジェクトが存在します。
これは iframe 内の `window` と同じものです。
**幾つかの条件を満たす時には**、外側のフレームから
この `contentWindow` の内部を書き換えることができます

このことを利用して `contentWindow.console.log` やその他を別の関数に差し替えてしまえば、
iframe 内から `console.log` への出力(全履歴)を、外側から知ることができます。
おおよそのコードはこんな感じですね。

```
// 文章内の最初の iframe を取得する。必要に応じて取り方は変えるべし
var firstFrame = document.getElementsByTagName('iframe')[0];

firstFrame.contentWindow.console.log = function() {
  // TODO: arguments を履歴として記録する
}
```

なお **幾つかの条件** とはおおよそ以下のとおりで、全て満たしている場合にのみ書き換え可能なはずです。(動作確認はしていない)

- iframe ノードが document の下にぶら下がっている
- 外側と iframe 内のコンテンツの生成元(オリジン)が同一である
- sandbox 制限がかかっていない

参考文献: [インラインフレームについて - JavaScriptプログラミング講座](http://hakuhin.jp/js/iframe.html)

## オリジンが異なる場合

仮に iframe 内側のコンテンツに任意のJavaScriptを入れられるようならば、
オリジンが異なる場合にも対応する方法があります。
それは [`parent.postMessage`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ja/docs/DOM/window.postMessage) を使う方法です。

説明は、簡単なコードを示すに留めますが以下のようになります。
なおコードには onload からの呼び出しなどは含まれていませんので、
必要に応じて適宜補ってください。

#### iframe の内側の JavaScript

```
console.log = function () {
  parent.postMessage(JSON.stringify(arguments), '*')
}
```

#### 外側の JavaScript

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);

function receiveMessage(ev) {
  // 期待した生成元(オリジン)からのメッセージであるかを確認する
  if (ev.origin === 'http://example.org/') {
    // 履歴に記録する
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Google Chromeの拡張からであれば、 [chrome.experimental.devtools.console API](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/experimental_devtools_console)を利用してコンソールの履歴にアクセスできます。

このAPIは開発者ツール内からしか利用できないので、開発者ツールを拡張する「拡張」として書く必要があります。そしてログを取得するには開発者ツールを開く必要がある、という制約が付きます。また実験段階のAPIなので、ブラウザの設定をいじって利用を許可する必要もあります。流れとしては:

1. chrome://flags/#extension-apis を開き、"Experimental Extension APIs"を有効にしておく
2. experimental パーミッションを manifest.json に含め、 devtools_page でHTMLファイルを指定する

   ```
   ...
   "permissions": [
     "experimental"
   ],
   "devtools_page": "devtools.html",
   ...
   ```
3. devtools.html から参照されるスクリプトで履歴用 API を使う

のようになります。

### 元のドキュメントに出力する

[メッセージングAPI](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/messaging)を利用して、開発者ツール内から元のドキュメントに出力できます:

devtools.html から参照されるスクリプトからメッセージを送信し:

```
// <script src="devtools.js"></script> などで指定したファイル内
chrome.experimental.devtools.console.onMessageAdded.addListener(function(message) {
  chrome.runtime.sendMessage({
    "to": chrome.devtools.inspectedWindow.tabId,
    "payload": message
  });
});
```

[Event Page](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/event_pages)のスクリプトで受け取り、[Content Script](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts)に中継する:

```
// マニフェストの "background": {"scripts": [...]} で指定したファイル内
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  chrome.tabs.sendMessage(message.to, message.payload, sendResponse);
});
```

Content Script側で元のドキュメントに出力する:

```
// マニフェストの "content_scripts": [...] で指定したファイル内
chrome.runtime.onMessage.addListener(function(message, sender, sendResponse) {
  var log = document.createElement('div');
  log.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(message);
  document.body.appendChild(log);
});
```

[開発者ツール用拡張のドキュメント](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/devtools#solutions)でもメッセージングAPIを使ういくつかのユースケースが解説されています。

Answer (score 0):

直接console.logの履歴にアクセスする方法ではありませんが、[Sinon.js](http://sinonjs.org)のようなテストフレームワークを使うと同様の事が出来そうです。
例えば、メソッドが呼ばれた時の引数や戻り値、エラーなどを監視するSpyを使うと、以下のような感じでconsole.logの引数に渡された文字列を取得できます（firstlogに"hoge"、secondlogに"moge"が入ります）。

```
var spy = sinon.spy(console, "log");
console.log("hoge");
console.log("moge");
var firstlog = spy.getCall(0).args[0];
var secondlog = spy.getCall(1).args[0];
```